# angular 7 style attribute value from an array dynamically

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-style

I am creating a progress bar using code below.

```
<td class="pBar">
  <label>{{kpiCriteriaLevel[i]['High_Impact']}}%</label>
  <br/>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': kpiCriteriaLevel[i]['Low_Impact'] }">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

This part of string interpolation `{{kpiCriteriaLevel[i]['High_Impact']}}` is coming from component file. But the same value is unable to read in `style` tag of HTML.

In the inspect element of browser I see - `ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width: 0px;"`

Please help, how to dynamically add value to `width` dynamically.

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me. Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qciozv) example of your code.

Comment: @Viqas thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry. Angular will update the value automatically as soon as you update the value in the component file as it uses `rxjs` under the hood.